# Matlab 2015b taking a very long time to overwrite files

Tags: matlab, save

Has anyone observed that Matlab 2015b takes a long time to overwrite an existing large `.mat` file with a table containing nested tables. Why is this happening?

For example:

```
t1 = table([1:1000].');
t1.Var2 = arrayfun(@(ind) array2table(rand(5000, 20)), ...
    t1.Var1, 'uni', 0);

t2 = table([1:1000].');
t2.Var2 = arrayfun(@(ind) array2table(rand(5000, 20)), ...
    t2.Var1, 'uni', 0);

t3 = table([1:1000].');
t3.Var2 = arrayfun(@(ind) array2table(rand(5000, 20)), ...
    t3.Var1, 'uni', 0);
```

On my computer, in a new directory:

```
tic;save('data_tmp_test.mat', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
tic;save('data_tmp_test.mat', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
Elapsed time is 71.284510 seconds.
Elapsed time is 433.225864 seconds.

tic;save('data_tmp_test_2', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
tic;save('data_tmp_test_2', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
Elapsed time is 73.059878 seconds.
Elapsed time is 360.631504 seconds.

tic;save('data_tmp_test_3', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
tic;save('data_tmp_test_3.mat', 't1', 't2', 't3', '-v7.3');toc
Elapsed time is 71.154672 seconds.
Elapsed time is 430.523112 seconds.
```

This only happens sometimes, but once it happens once, it happens very consistently. I have tested with other tables without the nested table, and those do not exhibit this behaviour while overwriting.

Comment: could it be that the OS is still writing the file?

Comment: but matlab is not busy anymore after writing the first file.